# Querying Mysql with PDO fetch returns false

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to query my database in PDO and have the output on a form. However the fetch statement does not work. The code is

```
try {
include '../../config/database.php';
$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();


//prepare query
$query = "select 
            payment_id, payment_supplier, payment_ref, payment_cost_rating, payment_amount 
        from 
            payments 
        where 
            payment_id = ? 
        limit 0,1";

$stmt = $db->prepare( $query );

//this is the first question mark
$stmt->bindParam(1, $_REQUEST['myData']);

//execute our query
if($stmt->execute()){
var_dump($stmt->fetch());
    //store retrieved row to a variable
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

    //values to fill up our form
    $payment_id = $row['payment_id'];
    $payment_supplier = $row['payment_supplier'];
    $payment_ref = $row['payment_ref'];
    $payment_cost_rating = $row['payment_cost_rating'];
    $payment_amount = $row['payment_amount'];

}else{
    echo "Unable to read record.";
}
```

}

```
var_dump ($stmt); prints
```

`object(PDOStatement)#3 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(157) "select payment_id, payment_supplier, payment_ref, payment_cost_rating, payment_amount from payments where payment_id = ? limit 0,1" }`

But `fetch()` always returns false. This is the included database.php file if it helps

```
class Database{

// database credentials
private $host = "localhost";
private $db_name = "test-project";
private $username = "root";
private $password = "";
public $conn;

// get the database connection
public function getConnection(){

    $this->conn = null;

    try{
        $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
    }catch(PDOException $exception){
        echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
    }

    return $this->conn;
}}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the fetch being used twice.

**It can be done this way:**

```
if($stmt->execute()){
    //store retrieved row to a variable
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

     // display the row after fetching the contents.
    var_dump($row); 

    //values to fill up our form
    $payment_id = $row['payment_id'];
    $payment_supplier = $row['payment_supplier'];
    $payment_ref = $row['payment_ref'];
    $payment_cost_rating = $row['payment_cost_rating'];
    $payment_amount = $row['payment_amount'];

}else{
    echo "Unable to read record.";
}
```

This should work well.

Answer (score -1):

Add checking of execute result and see error:

```
if($stmt->execute()){
    ...
}else{
    echo "Unable to read record:". print_r($stmt->errorInfo(), true);
}
```

Comment: The 'else' statement is never called as $stmt->execute; works. However calling fetch() does not work

Comment: You limit results with only one record, then you'll see returned record in your var_dump(..fetch) or no records if query returns empty result. And next calls of fetch() will fails after var_dump(..fetch) always. If fetch is always false, I advice you to check your query and it's result in any sql-client program.